# The function of finite exchangeable random variable have the same probability distribution?

Tags: probability

Assumet that $a_1, a_2,\ldots,a_i,\ldots, a_n$ is $n$ [exchangeable random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), $f$ is any function, $a_{\sigma_1}, a_{\sigma_2}, \ldots, a_{\sigma_n}$ is the permutation of $\{a_i\}$. Can we get that all the random variables $b_i = f(a_{\sigma_1}, a_{\sigma_2}, \ldots, a_{\sigma_n})$ ($1\leq i \leq n!$) have the same probability distribution.

Even this conclusion seems intuitive, I cannot find explicit (and formal) explanation about it. Can someone explain it or provide some thoughts, books, or links about it. Thanks for your kind help.